# Host a web Application

Tags: python, html, web, hosting

i am willing to build a web app that makes some calculations with python at backend.But i do not know how and where to  host it.İ have done some research but all i found is basically  putting html css js file online , not server side code.It would be great if anybody recommend me any tutorial etc.

Comment: Probably you can start here [python web app](https://realpython.com/python-web-applications)

Comment: Take a look at Heroku. It allows to build and deploy applications in different technologies including python. Read the developers doc here https://devcenter.heroku.com/start